# Named query not known - Annotations & Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Named query not known:
```

Entity class header:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery( callable = true, name = "_Foo_SP", query = "call _Foo()", readOnly = true, resultClass = Foo.class )
public class Foo {
   //...properties omitted for brevity
}
```

In the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <mapping
        class="com.company.test.Foo" />
```

And in a test class:

```
private static HibernateTemplate HIBERNATE_TEMPLATE;

public static void main( final String[] args ) {
    HIBERNATE_TEMPLATE =
        new HibernateTemplate( new AnnotationConfiguration().addAnnotatedClass( Foo.class ).configure().buildSessionFactory() );
    new HibernateTest().test();
}

public void test() {
    List findByNamedQuery = HIBERNATE_TEMPLATE.findByNamedQuery( "_Foo_SP" );
    for( Object object : findByNamedQuery ) {
        System.out.println( object );
        System.out.println( object.getClass().getName() );
    }
}
```

I had this working without annotations (eg: with the mapping in a mapping file) but it seems more intuitive to simply use the JPA annotations to declare mappings - but I can't seem to get it to work.

What am I doing wrong here? Is what I'm trying to do even possible? It seems I'm not the only one to encounter this, see: [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2394487).

I'm using hibernate 3.5.6-FINAL FWIW.

TIA

Comment: I have tried by myself your sample and it works fine. Try to remove <mapping class="com.company.test.Foo"/> from hibernate.cfg.xml once you have declared it in the AnnotationConfiguration

Comment: I just tried that and it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the wrong @Entity class. When I used:

```
org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
```

I would get the problems above. However, once I switched to:

```
javax.persistence.Entity
```

It works!

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer!