# "Named query not known" for named Hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

What might be the problem?

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries( {
    @NamedQuery(name = User.ALL,
                query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
})

public class User {
    public static final String ALL = "User.all";
}

public class Service {
    find... with ... User.ALL
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: User.all
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    at $Session_a5ad46cfa25.getNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
    at $Session_a5ad46cf913.getNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
    at de.medicshare.dal.HibernateCrudServiceDAO.findUniqueWithNamedQuery(HibernateCrudServiceDAO.java:83)
    at $CrudServiceDAO_a5ad46cfa19.findUniqueWithNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
    at $CrudServiceDAO_a5ad46cfa1b.findUniqueWithNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
    at $CrudServiceDAO_a5ad46cf931.findUniqueWithNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
    at de.medicshare.pages.Signup.proceedSignup(Signup.java:82)
    at de.medicshare.pages.Signup.dispatchComponentEvent(Signup.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:923)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1106)
    ... 90 more
```

Comment: why didn't you use just name="User.all"?

Comment: Eclipse can only confirm usage of constants. So, if I create the query with `"User.all"` it is a string that does not get checked. Using `User.ALL` gets checked before compiling if I spell it wrong.

Comment: Can you post your hibernate.cfg.xml/persistence.xml?

Comment: Turn on your "hibernate.log" and check if appears a string like "[org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder] (main:) Binding Named query: User.all => SELECT u FROM User u"... Then check your persistence file and check if the class User is mapped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Named query not known - Annotations & Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037107/named-query-not-known-annotations-hibernate)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will be your issue but check out this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037107/named-query-not-known-annotations-hibernate).

The issue was the use of:

```
org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
```

Instead of:

```
javax.persistence.Entity
```

Comment: That's a good point to notice, but I used the proper import in mace case, unfortunately.

Comment: Ahh well worth a try. Have you declared the class in your hibernate.cfg.xml (extensions at end can vary) as a <mapping>?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I renamed an Entity class in my package.
Make sure the full class name for the persistence unit in the persistence.xml matches your Entity class. e.g.

```
   <persistence-unit name="your_PU_name" transaction-type="JTA">
      ...
      <class> [ make sure here is the FQN of your entity class ] </class>
      ...
   </persistence-unit>
```